# Check whether NSManagedObject Array has a value for a particular key using contains

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsmanagedobject

Hello I am new to CoreData and been exploring it. Here the situation is I am downloading data from API call and storing it in CoreData and then later fetching all the data from CoreData.

This task is done on viewDidLoad method. So every time I open my application it calls this method and data is being downloaded. At also view did i store all of my data in an NSManagedObject array for a particular key.

Now this flow does duplicate entries in my CoreData. So what I want to do is I want keep the flow as it is. But whenever the data is fetched from API I want to check whether the data is available in that array or not? If yes then don't insert it into CoreData Entity, or else enter the data. The reason behind this flow is whenever the API gets updated it only downloads that data and insert it into CoreData else it fetches from Local CoreData itself.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
var allImageData:[Any] = []
var image: [NSManagedObject] = []

let urlForData = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    indicator.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(0.0), width: CGFloat(40.0), height: CGFloat(40.0))
    indicator.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

    indicator.startAnimating()


    callToFetchJson()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func callToFetchJson() { //1st This Function will be called

    let request = URLRequest(url: urlForData!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if data == nil && error == nil {
            print("no data")
        }
        else if data != nil && error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.decodingJson(data!)
            }

        }
        }.resume()
}


func saveToDB(_ name: String) {//This function is called to save image name to CoreData and it is called from decodingJson function

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ImageDetails",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let imageX = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                 insertInto: managedContext)

    imageX.setValue(name, forKey: "imageName")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        image.append(imageX)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func decodingJson(_ data: Data ) { //If we get data from API then this function will be called
    do {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
        let allImage = data
        allImageData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allImage, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [Any]

        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity =
            NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ImageDetails",
                                       in: managedContext)!

        let imageX = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: managedContext)

        for xImg in allImageData {
            let aImg = xImg as! [String:AnyObject]
            let aImgName = aImg["name"] as! String
            // I want some condition to check image array contains  aImgName or not forKey: imageName   
            //Here I want a check whether the data we got after decoding json is available in image array or not. 
            //If it is available then don't call saveToDB func. Otherwise call it.             
            // Following I have tried
            imageX.setValue(aImgName, forKey: "imageName")
            if !self.image.contains(imageX) {
                saveToDB(aImgName)
                print("Data inserted")
            }
            //Above code is failing to do its task. So is there any other way?

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {

    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allImageData.count;
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) {
    print("You selected item #:\(indexPath.item)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! tableViewCell

    let imageX = image[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = imageX.value(forKey: "imageName") as? String

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: You need to perform a fetch of all data before the repeat loop, then you can compare the names in the loop. And cast the JSON deserialization to `[[String:Any]]` since you certainly know the object is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: @vadian what should I need to do?

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing because it uses several nested method calls including redundant Core Data code. You already got a fetch in `viewDidLoad`. Map the result with the `map` function to an array of the image names. Then you can use the `contains` function. I would put everything to decode the JSON and create the `NSManagedObject` instances in the completion block of the data task.

Comment: Another way would be to just query the database for entries which are equal to the current item. This can be achieved by using a NSPredicate.

Comment: is this can be solution because it doesn't seem to be working :

imageX.setValue(aEmpName, forKey: "imageName")

                
                if (!self.image.contains(imageX)) {
                    saveToDB(aEmpName)
                }

Comment: @vadian I have updated the code. Have a look. If you still fail to understand then please tell me.

Comment: You removed the fetch in `viewDidLoad`. The fetch is important. Your workflow has to be 1) Load JSON data asynchronously 2) In the completion block fetch Core Data objects 3) map Core Data objects to *nameList* `[String]` 4) parse JSON 5) In the loop check if the `name` is in *nameList* if not create a new `NSManagedObject` 6) After the loop save the context and 7) reload the table view on the main thread.

Comment: @vadian Isn't there any way to create closure and check? Because I don't want to check everytime the loop iterates. I just want o apply any Filter If available using NSPredicate.

Comment: You need the loop anyway to parse the JSON and the `contains` function applied to a string array is very fast.

Comment: for subComments in self.comments {
                        if (subComments.value(forKey: "id") as! Int) == (comment["id"] as! Int) {
                            flag = false
                        }
                    }......... I have this solution I know as you told to loop anyway. But without above is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but for anyone who is looking for this If you want unique data what you can do is add a constraint like below

[image]

Then in your AppDelegate add add this

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MarketPulse")

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump

    return container
}()
```

we have added a merge policy so if there is data already present it will update if not it will insert